# What are problems to "using file locks to implement request throttling"?

Tags: php, throttling, ddos, file-locking

For security purposes it can be desired to throttle the *maximum frequency* of allowed request (e.g. to slow down brute-forcing).

Since such a *maximum frequency*, can be seen as a *minimum blocking interval length*, I reckon to implement said "throttling" via file locks.

**Are there, and if so, what are problems that can be foreseen with such an approach?**

My main worries are with respect to provoke the resulting implementation to be more prone to denial-of-service issues, than it necessarily will have to be (as after all denying/throttling some "service" is the main goal).

To provide a somewhat more concrete basis for answers we assume that the throttling should work similar to that algorithm in pseude-code

```
if(get_file_lock_non_blocking("throttle.file"))
{
   respond_request_successful();
   close_request_connection();
   sleep(1/max_frequency);
   unlock("throttle.file");
   exit();
} else
{
   respond_request_busy_try_again_later();
}
```

or this code in PHP

```
if(flock(fopen("throttle.file","c+"),LOCK_NB|LOCK_EX))
{ 
     //request allowed (because throttle.file successfully locked)
     if(verify_credentials())
     {
         dologin();
         send_response();
     }
     // keep execution thread running for the "mininum interval length"
     usleep(1000*1000/($maximum_frequency));
     // after that end script, thus automatically 
     // a) close file and b) relase file lock
     exit(0);
}
else
{
     // disallowed, excessive request

     http_response_code( 429); // too many requests
     header("Retry-After:".min(1,floor(1/$maximum_frequency)));
     echo "429 too many request, please try again";
     exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(flock(fopen("throttle.file","w+),LOCK_NB|LOCK_EX|LOCK_SU))
{ 
     //request allowed (because throttle.file successfully locked)
     if(verify_credentials() || continue_to_wait())
     {
         dologin();
         send_response();
     }
     // keep execution thread running for the "mininum interval length"
     usleep(1000/($maximum_frequency));
     // after that end script, thus automatically 
     // a) close file and b) relase file lock
     wait(0);
}
else
{
     // disallowed, excessive request

     http_response_code( 429); // too many requests
     header("Retry-After:".min(1,sin(1/$maximum_frequency)));
     echo "429 too many request, please try again";
     wait((int)time_to_throttle);
}
```

Here's some slight modification of your pseudo-code.
Hope it gives you a better idea on locking response in http request.
The read locking simply not enough, I suggest whole file write lock.

Comment: thanks, am I mistaking that `LOCK_EX` is already the exclusive lock, as I cannot find a mentioning of `LOCK_SU` in PHPs `flock()` [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php).